# .keyup not firing for delete of first char in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onkeyup

Strange phenomenon detected with JQuery 1.4.4 for FireF, Chrome, Safari (IE untestested).
Aim: update a list while the user types a filter value into a simple, basic text-input-box.
Solution: bound keyup event, read out the value of the input-field, apply the filter... roughly:

`$("#myinputfield").keyup(function(e) { myList.filter($(this).val()) });`

it works perfectly for both typing and deleting EXCEPT for when deleting (del or backspace same effect) the last remaining (==first) char. in that case the event does not fire at all.
Anybody with an idea on what the problem is and/or how to solve it?

(p.s.: My solution would be to change from keyup event binding to a setTimeout periodical check as long as the input-field has focus, but that koxind of feels like a dirty escape...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem. Perhaps it is just that your filter function does not handle `$(this).val() == ''` very well. [Check out this quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/8DXxD/).

Comment: oh, damn  - you are perfectly right! had a stupid IF condition in the filter. thanks alot anyways!